# Classifying Critical Points of $f(x,y)=xy-x+2x^3-yx^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization

I am classifying the critical point(s) of $ f(x,y)=xy-x+2x^3-yx^3  $:

I first found the critical points by solving for $ f_x=f_y=0 $:

$f_x= y-1+6x^2-3yx^2=0  $

$f_y= x-x^3=0$

Hence $x=0$ and $y=1$.

Now I need to use the formula $D=D(a,b)=f_{xx}(a,b)\space f_{yy}(a,b)-[f_{xy}(a,b)]^2 $ to classify the found $ (a,b) $ critical point which is $(0,1)$.

$f_{xx}=12x-6yx$

$f_{yy}=0$

$[f_{xy}]^2=[1-3x^2]^2=1-6x^2+9x^4$

hence, $D=-1+6x^2-9x^4$, so $D(0,1)=-1$

Now to find the critical points I am given the conditions for different kinds of critical points (classification), Since $D\lt 0$, is the only critical point of $ f(x,y)=xy-x+2x^3-yx^3  $ a saddle point? If so, are there any other possible critical points I should consider or is there anything else I should provide in my answer?

Comment: $x=0$ is not the only possible x-value.  There is also $x=\pm 1$.

Comment: how did you solved the equationsystem $$f_x=0,f_y=0$? there are more solutions

Comment: For $f_y=x-x^3=x(1-x^2)=0$, so there is another solution of $ x=\pm1$ ?

Comment: So then in this case, $ D(1,1)=D(-1,1)=-4 $. Since $ D \lt 0 $, does this mean that  there are two more saddle points, one at (-1,1) and another at (1,1)?

Comment: That is correct.